# Reading Stream and open that document

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I have a stream object in which I have some document, I know what document is it, how can I open that document without saving it into a file physically. So I want to directlly open the document from stream itself without saving it.

How to do that? I doing it in c#

Comment: What type of document is that? How do you "open" it? What prevents you from saving the file to a temporary directory?

Comment: If you don't tell us, we don't know what document you have. That makes it hard to find a solution.

Comment: @Jens may be I don't have access to write the file in temp dir itself

Comment: I am planning to attach the document in response and the to use Response.BinaryWrite, is this will work for all or not

Comment: so, is this a web based solution?

Comment: yes, it is a web based solution. Also this Stream is of MemoryStream type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i do such a thing, but i know the file's name. this is method is called into an empty aspx page (i mean without any kind of html markup except the <@Page ... /> line )

```
private void LoadAttachment()
    {
            byte[] ImageData = ... get data from somewhere ...

            Response.Buffer = true;
            String filename = "itakethis.fromdatabase";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
            Response.ContentType = GetMimeType(filename);//you can try to extrapolate it from file extension
            if(ImageData.Length > 0)
                Response.BinaryWrite(ImageData);
            else
                Response.BinaryWrite(new byte[1]);
            Response.Flush();
            ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

`

Comment: there's some useful stuff there, but the OP is asking about `Stream` not `byte[]`, and since you check for `.Length` your solution will not translate.

Comment: @Kirk Woll, sorry, my mistake, i thougth the problem was to  physically save the file, not to directly use the stream. Anyway, streams have a length property. If the problem is to directly use the stream, then the answer is no : bynarywrite take a byte array as argument

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to use the document only in RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most programs (Word, Excel, Notepad, ...) need a filename to open a file. So i think there is no real solution to your problem.

The only think would be to write a [File System Filter Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx), that returns the MemoryStream for a virtual filename, but that driver has to be written in C++ and is not the easiest one to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you save the file?

I've used `GetTempFilename` to good effect in the past. I can't remember exactly which class it's in, probably `System.Environment` or `File` itself. Anyway, you can be sure the file will be in the system defined temp folder, so you can safely delete the file once you're done with it.